# Filtering NDIS-Protocoldrivers with WFP

Tags: ndis, wfp

The issue:
When I configure virtualbox or vmware player to work in the bridge network I am unable to prevent them from accessing the internet. I only want the main instance of Windows to be able to access the internet but I need to run them in bridged mode.

What I have tried:
I have written a callout-driver to log traffic at the individual layers. The only layer which allows me to block the traffic appears to be "FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_MAC_FRAME_NATIVE" at which point none of the provided information helps me distinguish the "bridge-traffic" from regular traffic. I have tried tagging the traffic in "FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_MAC_FRAME_ETHERNET" and then filtering it but this would result in a host of issues. Furthermore I have tried using the netbufferlist SourceHandle to no avail(e.g. to call NdisMQueryAdapterInstanceName).

My question:
Is there a way to filter this traffic? What am I missing?

Comment: Do the packets have a different source MAC address for each VM? In general, the only thing you can do with the SourceHandle is check if it is `==` your own SourceHandle. You cannot infer anything about other drivers' handles.

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, thanks for taking the time to respond to me. I can't easily access the mac address but I could see that being a delineating factor (that is if it can be read from the nbl as the callback doesn't supply it). However I found that newer NDIS versions add the return-addresses of it's creators in the actual poolhandle associated with the nbl. From that I can infer which driver created the packet and block them based on that. It might not be the best way but I would hope assume that's easier than reading the actual nbl data.

Comment: @Kazuma What did you do in the end? any update?